# Multiple file upload alternatives to Java Applets

Tags: java, php, file, flash, file-upload

What are some alternatives to multiple file upload besides Java Applets? It doesn't have to be in java, it can be flash, php, etc.

I currently have a website that uses a java applet for multi-file uploads; however, it's turning out to be more of a hassle now that Java blocks applets that are not signed. I have found out that I need a code signing certificate, which I would have to pay a fee / year. *I really want an alternative that would have the same functionality (Fast upload, multi-file upload, pause/continue file upload function) without having to incur the yearly expense of having to sign the applet yearly. I wouldn't mind paying an upfront fee for the program, it's the yearly fee that I am not quite sold on.*

I may just have to proceed with my current option, but I am curious to know if there are better solutions that meet the indicated requirements than what I am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

There's [this project over GitHub](https://github.com/mikestead/as3urlrequestbuilder), with a link to the blog post, that I recommend you to read fully. It's a workaround that doesn't seem to play nice with a Java backend, but it does with PHP.